# List of Images like Instagram

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I want to make a scrollable list of images like instagram with 4 columns.  I created a collection view with image views http://prntscr.com/d15rnx . But I get this result - http://prntscr.com/d15tsq 
code -

```
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

// tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "main/p\(self.items[indexPath.item].code)/main/main.jpg")
    print("main_card_images/p\(self.items[indexPath.item].code)/main/main")
    return cell
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    print(self.items[indexPath.item])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let yourNextViewController = (segue.destination as! ViewControllerCard)
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: sender as! UICollectionViewCell)
    yourNextViewController.mainCardImage = self.items[(indexPath?.item)!]
}
```

Comment: so you want to close the gap nicely with little space ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set inter cell spacing to 0 and then all you have to do is implement:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

      return(collectionView.bounds.size.width/4,collectionView.bounds.size.height/4)
}
```

This will resize all cells to be equal to 1/4 the `UICollectionView` width and thus create 4 cells in each row(1/4 the height value is just cause i like symmetry in these types of UI). If there appears to be any less number of cells than that, its because the inter-item spacing has not been set to 0. If you want inter-item spacing, just subtract that value from the width value returned in the above function

**Alternatively**

You can implement your own custom flow layout but the above solution is far more simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it easiest to configure my collection view via the setting in Interface Builder. For a collection view with a flow layout here are the settings I use for the insets. I have found the item size width: 125.8 and height: 125.8 to give me the best size for displaying on most devices in portrait or landscape.

[image]

Here's what my collection view looks like.

[image]

You can of course set this programmatically using [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617718-collectionview) or as Rikh suggests by subclassing [CollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout)